# How to stop all currently playing clips in Java before playing a new one?

Tags: java, swing, javax.sound.sampled

I am making a Smart ATM application for my college project using Swing which can be used by people with visual disabilities as well.

I have added mouse over listeners to every button so that the program plays a clip which speaks about the operation of that button.

The problem is when user hovers over multiple buttons in a short period of time when a clip about previous button is already getting played, two clips get played simultaneously which is not what I want.

My code so far for the current frame is:

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.Clip;
import javax.swing.*;



public class InitialInput extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    JLabel logo;
    JPanel logoPanel = new JPanel();

    JPanel askPanel = new JPanel();
    JPanel pinPanel = new JPanel();

    //For adding span
    JPanel emptyPanel = new JPanel();

    JTextField accountNumberField = new JTextField(10);
    JLabel askAccountNumber = new JLabel("Please enter your account Number : ");
    public int userAccountNumber;

    JTextField pinField = new JTextField(10);
    JLabel askPin = new JLabel("Please enter your Pin : ");
    public int userPin;

    JPanel submitPanel = new JPanel();
    JButton submit = new JButton("SUBMIT");
    JButton createAccount = new JButton("CREATE NEW ACCOUNT");
    JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    Clip clipAccountNumberField,clipPinField,clipWelcome,clipSubmit;
    InitialInput() {
        //Play welcome Music
        try {
            AudioInputStream audioIn = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(Welcome.class.getResource("WelcomeMusic.wav"));
            clipWelcome = AudioSystem.getClip();
            clipWelcome.open(audioIn);
            clipWelcome.start();
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Sorry Unable to play deposit music!");
        }
        buildGUI();


    }
    //TODO Work on this
    /*
    public void stopAllClips() {
        //Clip clipAccountNumberField,clipPinField,clipWelcome,clipSubmit;
        if(clipWelcome.isActive())
            clipWelcome.stop();
        if(clipAccountNumberField.isActive())
            clipAccountNumberField.stop();
        if(clipPinField.isActive())
            clipPinField.stop();
        if(clipSubmit.isActive())
            clipSubmit.stop();
        }*/
    public void buildGUI() {
        //Properties of Frame
        setSize(400,300);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        try {

            BufferedImage logoI = ImageIO.read(this.getClass().getResource("logo.png"));
            logo = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(logoI));
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            e.getMessage();     

        }
        //On Hover Action for Deposit Button
        accountNumberField.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseEntered(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                try {
                    AudioInputStream audioIn = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(InitialInput.class.getResource("ClickAndEnterAccountNumber.wav"));
                    clipAccountNumberField = AudioSystem.getClip();
                    clipAccountNumberField.open(audioIn);
                    //  stopAllClips();
                    clipAccountNumberField.start();
                }
                catch(Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("Sorry Unable to play account number music!");
                }

            }
        });
        pinField.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseEntered(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                try {
                    AudioInputStream audioIn = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(InitialInput.class.getResource("ClickAndEnterPin.wav"));
                    clipPinField = AudioSystem.getClip();
                    clipPinField.open(audioIn);
                    //  stopAllClips();
                    clipPinField.start();
                }
                catch(Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("Sorry Unable to play pin music!");
                }

            }
        });
        submit.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseEntered(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                try {
                    AudioInputStream audioIn = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(InitialInput.class.getResource("ClickToSubmit.wav"));
                    clipSubmit = AudioSystem.getClip();
                    clipSubmit.open(audioIn);
                    //  stopAllClips();
                    clipSubmit.start();
                }
                catch(Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("Sorry Unable to play submit  music!");
                }

            }
        });
        //TODO Add music to create account button
        //Adds gap between create account and submit button
        FlowLayout flow = new FlowLayout(); // Create a layout manager
        flow.setHgap(35);          
        submitPanel.setLayout(flow);

        //Adds symbiosis logo to panel
        logoPanel.add(logo);

        //Adds action listener to text fields
        accountNumberField.addActionListener(this);
        pinField.addActionListener(this);
        //Adds action listener to Create Account Button
        createAccount.addActionListener(this);
        //Adds labels to panel
        askPanel.add(askAccountNumber);
        askPanel.add(accountNumberField);

        //Adds textfields to panel
        pinPanel.add(askPin);
        pinPanel.add(pinField);

        //Adds buttons to panels
        submitPanel.add(createAccount);
        submitPanel.add(submit);

        //Specifies constraints for grid layout
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
        c.gridx=0;
        c.gridy=0;
        mainPanel.add(logoPanel,c);

        c.gridx=0;
        c.gridy=1;
        mainPanel.add(askPanel,c);

        c.gridx=0;
        c.gridy=2;
        mainPanel.add(emptyPanel,c);

        c.gridx=0;
        c.gridy=3;
        mainPanel.add(pinPanel,c);

        c.gridx=0;
        c.gridy=4;
        mainPanel.add(emptyPanel,c);

        c.gridx=0;
        c.gridy=5;
        mainPanel.add(submitPanel,c);

        add(mainPanel);
        setVisible(true);
    }
    //Action listener
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(e.getSource()==accountNumberField) {
            try {
                userAccountNumber = Integer.parseInt(accountNumberField.getText());
                int numberOfDigitsInAccountNumber = String.valueOf(userAccountNumber).length();
                if(numberOfDigitsInAccountNumber !=6) {
                    throw new InputMismatchException();
                }
                if(userAccountNumber <= 0) {
                    throw new Exception();
                }
                //TODO if(accountNumber) not present in database 
            }
            catch(InputMismatchException e1) {
                accountNumberField.setText("");
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(accountNumberField,"Please enter a 6 digit account number.");
            }
            catch(Exception e1) {
                accountNumberField.setText("");
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(accountNumberField,"Invalid input.");
            }
        }
        else if(e.getSource()==pinField) {
            try {
                userPin = Integer.parseInt(pinField.getText());
                int numberOfDigitsInAccountNumber = String.valueOf(userPin).length();
                if(numberOfDigitsInAccountNumber !=4) {
                    throw new InputMismatchException();
                }
                if(userPin <= 0) {
                    throw new Exception();
                }
                //TODO if(accountNumber) not match in database 
            }
            catch(InputMismatchException e1) {
                pinField.setText("");
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(pinField,"Please enter a 4 digit pin.");
            }
            catch(Exception e1) {
                pinField.setText("");
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(pinField,"Invalid input.");
            }
        }
        else if(e.getSource()==createAccount) {
            CreateAccount a = new CreateAccount();
            this.setVisible(false);
            a.setVisible(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override the mouseExited method for each MouseListener, stopping the Clip in the implementation

```
@Override
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e){
    theClipIManage.stop();
}
```